# Compiler Error C2065 using OpenMP clause Private

Tags: c++, openmp

My problem in the follows. I am implementing the assembly of the stiffness matrix (finite elements and surroundings) and I am doing it using the OpenMP directives. Beyond the specific problem, the compiler complains about the C2065 error:

> 'k' : undeclared identifier

Reading different guides in the examples that were reported the syntax was the same as mine. The main problem is that it doesn't recognize the variable that is set as private. Can anyone help me understand why?
(of course I used #include <omp.h>)

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp for private(k)
    for (int k = 0; k < nElem; k++)
    {
        coeff = matricesAssemblingCSR(topol, coeff, A_loc, ja, iat, k);
        matrix = matricesAssembling(topol, matrix, A_loc, k);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Sure, my bad. The error is:  'k' : undeclared identifier

Comment: You've stuffed `k` into the `private` directive before the compiler has seen it, `k`.  You don't need to tell the compiler that the loop index variable is to be private, OpenMP takes care of that for you.  Just drop `private(k)` altogether.

Comment: Thank you, @HighPerformanceMark. But what about if I want to specify that **k** has to be private anyway?

Comment: I don't know much about OpenMP but how does assigning to the same two variables in parallel work? Are they atomic?

Comment: If you really want to specify it, you would have to declare it in front of the loop (`int k; #pragma ... for (k = 0; ...)`, but this is considered a code smell as this will cause `k` to have a bigger scope without any need for that. All variables declared inside the parallel region are private by default.

Comment: The loop variable in an `omp parallel for` is automatically private.